# What is BIP32-style derivation?

Tags: address, ecdh

I am reading the technical "specification" for stealth addresses, available [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/bitcoin/mailman/message/31813471/). The core idea is described in the following paragraph:

> Using Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) we can generate a shared
>   secret that the payee can use to recover their funds. Let the payee
>   have keypair Q=dG. The payor generates nonce keypair P=eG and uses
>   ECDH to arrive at shared secret c=H(eQ)=H(dP). This secret could be
>   used to derive a ECC secret key, and from that a scriptPubKey, however
>   that would allow both payor and payee the ability to spend the funds.
>   So instead we use BIP32-style derivation to create Q'=(Q+c)G and
>   associated scriptPubKey.

I understand everything except the last sentence. As far as I can tell, `Q` and `c` are known to the payee and payer so the keypair `Q'=(Q+c)G` is also known to both. How does `Q'` allow for only the payee to spend the funds? How does BIP32-style derivation work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a typo. It should instead read `Q'=(d+c)G=Q+cG`. The private part `d+c` is an offset of the payee's private part `d`, so only known to the payee. The public part is an offset `cG`, known to both.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help? https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#hierarchical-deterministic-key-creation

or check the various BIP32 implementations (bitcore for example)

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm generates a public key, which both parties know. It's just a public key, though, so only recipient has the ability to spend the funds.

According to the paper, `Q` is the recipient's stealth public key and `c` is the shared secret. The calculation `Q'=(Q+c)G` creates a shared public key derived from the receiver's stealth public key.

If the receiver's private stealth key is `d`, they can unlock the funds by calculating the new private key `(d+c)`. The sender doesn't know `d`, so they have no way of calculating this value.

BIP32 HD wallets use the same idea. You can start with a private key, `k`, and a public key `K = kG`. Then, you start adding random numbers (hashes, actually) to both keys. As long as you add the same number to both the private and the public key, you maintain a working keypair. You can reveal your public key `K`, which allows others to addresses, but they cannot spend from those addresses without knowing the private key `k`.